# Rewrite Pandas code to best leverage PySpark parallelization?

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I have recently begun working with PySpark. My goal is reimplement an existing algorithm and run on a Spark cluster to leverage distributed processing. Is there general guidance for rewriting an algorithm to best leverage Spark's parallel processing capabilities? My data is stored in a Delta Lake table, partitioned on a field `X`. In my code I have a `for`-loop that goes through each value for `X` and runs the algorithm, for example:

```
for target in props['targets']:
    df = spark.read.format('delta').load(table).filter((df['X'] == target))
    ...
```

Is there a better way to handle such looping in Spark? What I suppose I am missing from my understanding of Spark parallelization is whether or not the distribution across the executors is (mostly) hidden from the end-user, or if I need to "directly" tell Spark to distribute my algorithm? For example, could I write this code in such a way that each cycle of the loop runs in a separate executor in parallel, rather than the loop being run by the driver, or does Spark figure out itself the distribution across executors?

This code was originally written with Pandas reading local CSV, but just replacing the Pandas statements with equivalent PySpark statements has not given any speed improvements (even when running multiple executors).

Further, what about functions such as the following from [StatsModels](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/index.html)? The data parameter is array-like, which according to the docs is "any scalar or sequence that can be interpreted as an ndarray". So I cannot pass a PySpark column, I have to convert to a plain Pandas dataframe and pass one of its columns.

```
df = df.toPandas()
statsmodels.api.tsa.seasonal_decompose(df['myCol'], model=model, extrapolate_trend='freq', period=period)
```

This code, as far as I can tell, will run on the executor, which appears to be an expensive operation given that data will be shifted from executor to driver. Is there a better way to approach such functions?

I hope you catch the gist of my overall ask here. How best can one approach rewriting code for Spark to leverage its parallel processing capabilities? My gut tells me my approach so far is baked full of inefficiencies, but I lack the knowledge to spot and correct them.

Comment: you need to filter by all values of your targets using `isin` expression: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.isin.html

Comment: @AlexOtt How is this an improvement over the `filter` call that I am using?

Comment: You will avoid looping